# What does mean assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'float?

Tags: c, function, call

This is a error message:

> assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'float (const string, ...)' (aka 'float (char *const, ...)')

**Code:**

```
int main(void) {
  float n = -1;
  int z = 0;
  int counter = 0;
  do {
    printf("Input positive money amount such as $5.13 as '5.13' \n");
    n = get_float;
  } while (n < 0);
  n = n * 100;
  n = round(n);
  z = n;
  while (z >= 25) {
    z = z - 25;
    counter++;
  }
  while (z >= 10) {
    z = z - 10;
    counter++;
  }
  while (z >= 5) {
    z = z - 5;
    counter++;
  }
  while (z >= 1) {
    z = z - 1;
    counter++;
  }
  printf("number of minimum coins needed %d", counter);
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code?

Comment: @sabatilius Place the code in the question instead of the comment.

Answer (score 1):

In this expression statement

```
n = get_float;
```

the variable `n` has the type `float` while the expression `get_float` is function pointer `float ( * )(const string, ...)`.

You should write instead

```
n = get_float( "Input positive money amount such as $5.13 as '5.13: ' );
```

That is you need to call the function instead of assigning a pointer to the function to the variable `n`.